# Concatenate two numbers in Webi (not adding numbers)

Tags: business-objects, webi

I need to compare the first, middle and last test in each program year. The measurements for doing so involve two variables (1) Level (a text) and (2) score (a number).

There are 52 levels, which I have interpreted into a variable which translates each Level into a number: `([IReady - Level #])`. I would like to join the `([IReady - Level #])` variable with the Score associated with each test: `([Total Reading - Score_1965])`.

For example, my `([IReady - Level #])` variable translates the level named `Early 1` into the number 4. And it translates the next level, `Mid 1`, into the number 5. So an individual's original results from three tests taken during one program year might look like this:

- Test1 Level & Score: Early 1 & 301
- Test2 Level & Score: Mid 1 & 299
- Test3 Level & Score: Early 1 & 300

However, the goal is to use my `([IReady - Level #])` variable, joined with the Score `([Total Reading - Score_1965])` so that those test results would look like the following -- creating a new number that's easily comparable to one another and reliably reflects inter and intra- level progress:

- Test1 Level & Score: 4301
- Test2 Level & Score: 5299
- Test3 Level & Score: 4300

The following formula works (this variable's name is `[zzLevel + Score concatenated]`:

=`[IReady - Level #]` + "" + `[Total Reading - Score_1965]`

...but it turns the resulting number into a string, even after I've used the `ToNumber` function as listed below:

- over the larger variable

  ```
  =`ToNumber([zzLevel + Score concatenated]`
  ```
- within the `[IReady - Level #]` variable

  =`[IReady - Level #]=ToNumber(((If ([Total Reading - Level_1966] InList( "Emerging K"; "emerging K"; "emerging k")) Then 0`... 
  (And I've found that, even for this to work, I have to turn the `[IReady - Level #]` variable into a "Dimension" vs. a "Measure" in order for it to be read as a number. ) But it does, successfully, see this variable as a number, now. So now I just need to figure out how to concatenate two numbers.

Can someone help me with turning the result into a number? I probably have questions following this, but this is the most crucial aspect.

*UPDATE: with the help of an associate I've figured out another way to accomplish what I need--I've multiplied my Level # by 1,000: `([IReady - Level #]*1000)` ...so that I can just add that new variable to the score number. Now a test resulting in the level "Early 1" with a Score of "301" equals the sum: "4,301". However, I'm still curious if there's a way to join two numbers, (i.e. the number "100" + "401" = 100401--as a number vs. a string). So I still welcome any ideas for that.*

Comment: Can you show your attempt at using the ToNumber() function? What are some sample values of the variables you are trying to convert within the ToNumber() function?

Comment: Hi, Isaac, Yes I've added that into the description.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that converts numbers into strings: FormatNumber()

However, if you aren't actually wanting to format anything, and just want to convert a number to a string for the sort of concatenation you are mentioning, the easiest way is to just add a string to it.  If you use a null string, then you can convert it back to a number using ToNumber.  For example:

- `="Number: " + 100` - would assign a variable to the string value of "Number: 100"
- `=""+100` - would assign a variable to the string value of "100"
- `=100+""` - would also assign a variable to the string value of "100"
- `=100+""+401` - would assign a variable to the string value of "100401"
- `=""+100+401` - would also assign a variable to the string value of "100401"
- `=100+401+""` - would assign a variable to the string value of "501" (left to right calculation means it isn't converted to a string until the string is encountered, so it adds the numbers and then converts)
- `=ToNumber(100+""+401)` - would compute to the numeric value 100401